# Не подключаются стили в теме wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Пытаюсь создать свою первую тему на wordpress, при содействии курса Андрея Бернацкого и Андря Кудлая. Для начала закинул в файл index.php весь  html-код и немного js. Основные стили закинул в таблицу стилей style.css. Прописываю в файле functions.php следующий код:

```
/*
* Загружаемые скрипты и стили
*/
function load_style_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_my', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizCust', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.79639.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_my_two', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jq_ba_cond', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jq_slitslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slitslider.js');

    wp_enqueue_style('font_one', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
    wp_enqueue_style('font_two', 'http://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=a_stamperbrk');

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('css_demo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/demo.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('css_style_two', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('css_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('css_styleNoJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/styleNoJS.css');
}

/*
* Загружаем скрипты и стили
*/

add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'load_style_script');
```

Но стили не подключились и скрипты, хотя в курсе всё работает. В чём проблема и что я не так делаю? Тем я взял свою, не из курса, если что.

Comment: Почему не работает, пока не вижу, но черт возьми, кто вас научил подключать еще два jQuery к Wordpress? Чем вас существующий не устраивает?

Comment: @tutankhamun полагаю, что этими людьми были Андрей Бернацкий и Андрей Кудлай :)

Comment: @alenkins Называется "извините, вырвалось". Нередка ситуация, когда в покупной теме напихано десяток слайдеров и у каждого в прицепе свой jQuery. Все версии обязательно разные (наверное инече не интересно). Ну и в самой теме лежит еще один (а то и два - один на админку). Вот :)

Comment: Да ладно вам стебаться над начинающим) Я исправлюсь)) Можете книгу посоветовать на русском по wp лучше, чтобы я сюда лишний раз с тупыми вопросами не обращался)

Comment: @alenkins прости, что навязываюсь, но я даже не знаю к кому обратиться, помоги мне, плиз, с вордпрессом, можешь дать скайп или контакт из соц сети какой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строке

`add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'load_style_script');`

Функция `wp_enqueue_script()`, но хук пишется как `wp_enqueue_scripts` - с окончанием `s`, указывающим на множественное число.

Т. е. правильно будет

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_style_script');`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)